# Why is the memory of a global structure and a member variable (of the same type) set equal to the global different?

Tags: c++, memory, compare, structure

I am constructing an object like so:

`TestObj::TestObj(const TypedefStruct& myStruct) : m_memberStruct(myStruct){}`

The struct looks like this:

`typedef struct{ short x; short y;} TypedefStruct;`. it is a public member of `class TestObj`.`

When I compare the memory of the global `myStruct` being passed into the constructor and the `m_memberStruct` member variable of `TestObj`, the memory contents differ.

PS: I am initializing the global struct like so: `TestObj::TypeDefStruct myStruct = {0};`

I have read that compilers will sometimes pad the elements of a struct to make each element the same size, and that that can interfere with comparing the memory of a global struct and a "copy" of it, but I don't think that applies here because it is a same-type two-element struct...

Any insight on the situation?  If I cannot actually compare the memory besides just checking the values of the two elements I would still like to understand why the memory contents are different.

Comment: *How* do they differ? Can you post both dumps?

Comment: Please show more code. There seems to be no reason for this to happen. Also, what are the memory contents of the two versions?

Comment: How are you comparing the memory? Are you using `memcmp` in your program? Or are you dumping the memory in your debugger?

Comment: Please post a minimal compilable sample program that illustrates your problem. For more information about how to do that, and why it is a good idea, see http://sscce.org. In the meanwhile, I have created a minimal program for you ([here](http://ideone.com/8C3NF)), which provides the correct (intuitive) answer. How does my minimal program differ from yours?

Comment: Your question title is a [long] sentence. Please make it not.

Comment: Sorry Tom, I will work on my questions; I was just trying to be sufficiently descriptive;  Also, sorry to all that it took me so long to respond. I was having the problem at the end of the day and then went off on the long holiday weekend. I just got back, removed my quick-fix (checking the individual copied members), and ran a `memcmp()` on the two structs and they were the same; unfortunately I do not remember what I was doing last Friday to cause the unexpected results...

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can pad m_memberStruct because it is part of TestObj. That is, it may try to give TestObj proper alignment.

Comment: It could, but it won't. The structure that the OP provides in his sample program won't be padded on any compiler he is likely to run on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are looking at the data and not say the addresses of the objects?

You could try initializing the variables to easily recognized values and then looking:

```
myStruct.x = 0xAA;
myStruct.y = 0xBB;
```